# Jmeter perfmon :EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION

Tags: performance, jmeter, load-testing

I am trying to run a performance test of my server using jmeter perfmon plugin. But I am getting an error as in the following image. I have searched a lot for a solution but couldn't find an answer. I tried setting JVM arguments but it didn't work. [Link to error image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mAcLq.png)How can I get it worked?

```
INFO    2019-12-30 14:11:25.114 [kg.apc.p] (): Binding UDP to 4444
INFO    2019-12-30 14:11:25.155 [kg.apc.p] (): Binding TCP to 4444
INFO    2019-12-30 14:11:25.161 [kg.apc.p] (): JP@GC Agent v2.2.3 started
INFO    2019-12-30 14:11:37.974 [kg.apc.p] (): Accepting new TCP connection
INFO    2019-12-30 14:11:37.978 [kg.apc.p] (): Yep, we received the 'test' command
INFO    2019-12-30 14:11:37.979 [kg.apc.p] (): Starting measures: memory:       cpu:
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000010014ed4, pid=12236, tid=6844
JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (11.0.4+10) (build 11.0.4+10-LTS)
Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (11.0.4+10-LTS, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, g1 
gc, windows-amd64)
Problematic frame:
C  [sigar-amd64-winnt.dll+0x14ed4]
No core dump will be written. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows

An error report file with more information is saved as:
E:\\hs_err_pid12236.log

If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
```

Comment: Please refer this thread: https://github.com/hyperic/sigar/issues/141#issuecomment-733408751

Answer (score 2):

I downloaded another sigar 1.6.4 jar (1.6.4.129 (17.1.2016) release) from below link and replaced sigar jar with this in specific tool lib path (ServerAgent-2.2.3\lib).., then it worked for me.

https://javalibs.com/artifact/org.hyperic/sigar

Answer (score 2):

Follow the below step.

1. Disable firewall setting

if still having same issue

1. Download the below .dll file and replace it(lib folder)
   https://github.com/cnstar9988/sigar/raw/master/sigar-amd64-winnt.dll

Comment: this worked for me, replacing the dll

Answer (score 1):

Looking into [JVM crashes occassionally with access violation when using Sigar.getProcMem with disabled Windows performance counters #77 issue](https://github.com/hyperic/sigar/issues/77) it might be the case that [Windows don't have performance counters enabled](https://community.microstrategy.com/s/article/KB48059-How-to-enable-Windows-performance-counters-to?language=en_US) hence Sigar fails to query the CPU status from [Windows PerfMon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/perfmon)

1. Check if CPU (and other stats) are exposed in PerfMon
2. Try running [Powershell and Server Agent as Administrator](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/ways-launch-powershell-windows-admin)
3. Try using [cmd.exe interpreter](https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html) instead of powershell
4. Try [running `ServerAgent.bat --sysinfo`](https://github.com/undera/perfmon-agent#usage) to see if there are any errors there
5. Inspect `e:\hs_err_pid12236.log` file for any clues

If nothing helps be aware that you can use [SSHMon](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-monitor-server-resource-utilization-with-jmeters-sshmon-listener/) plugin for server monitoring, it doesn't require server-side software installation

Comment: Please tell me how to check if Cpu is exposed to Perfmon

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue. Error code as follows:

"JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (11.0+28) (build 11+28)
Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (11+28, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, windows-amd64)
Problematic frame:
C  [sigar-amd64-winnt.dll+0x14ed4]"

I downgraded the JDK and JRE to the version :  8u241

Go to the Oracle download page [here](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase8u211-later-archive-downloads.html#license-lightbox) and search for the below JRE & JDK and install it in the Windows server and then start the serverAgent.bat

jdk-8u241-windows-x64.exe

jre-8u241-windows-x64.exe

This should fix the issue 100% sure. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

It was solved at my end using the below steps:

1. Download ‘jre 1.8’ from this link https://java.com/en/download/win10.jsp
2. Once the jre is installed, copy the folder named ‘jre1.8.0_261’.
   [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ni3qy.png)
3. Visit the ServerAgent folder that was downloaded >> Paste the ‘jre1.8.0_261’ folder inside the ‘ServerAgent-2.2.1’ folder.
4. Open ‘startAgent.bat’ file in Notepad ++ >>Initially it would look like this
   [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50hK9.png)
5. Replace text ‘java’ with the path of java.exe that is within the jre folder placed inside the ServerAgent-2.2.1 folder
6. Open command prompt in the ServerAgent-2.2.1 folder path and enter ‘startAgent.bat’ file to run the file
7. Execute JMeter script and now error should not happen.